# Managing Multiple Selenium Sessions in Web Scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been working on a web scraping program in Python using the Selenium package. The program is deployed as a web service on a VM. The idea is that other users can access this web service on their own respective PCs and start the web scraping process.

I’m not entirely done with the program, but my research now shows that it isn’t possible to have multiple Selenium instances running at the same time on the server/VM. Is there a workaround for this? Will Playwright or other packages be more suited for this process?

The web pages the web service is scraping do require logging in with a username and password. So the user has to fill out a form in the web service interface.

I'm not an expert programmer, and I have no familiarity with multithreading. I would like to hear the easiest workaround for this issue.

The web service is hosted using the web framework Streamlit in Python as well.

Comment: you can create a thread per driver/browser pair.  It sounds like what you are looking for is Selenium Grid, though: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/

Comment: @browsermator Amazing. Thanks. Will look into it. EDIT: It’s only for Java?

Comment: I think so... never used it before.  If you can't do that, you might look into running it all on a dedicated machine.  (Also try something lightweight like HTMLUnit, though I think that's also Java only... HTMLUnit won't work for all sites so you'd need to test it a bit.)

Answer (score 0):

I had nothing to worry about. I did test it and Streamlit (the Tornado webserver) handles the concurrency for me.